# Overflow : scroll; remove the text displayed at border

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, margin

I am trying to make a small div element that looks like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8ykM/2/

Problem with this code is that if I try to add a `overflow-y : scroll` property to `#divPendingQues` then the text which is displayed at the border gets removed.

What could be the problem, I am unable to find out. :(

Comment: Why dont you use 'legend' instead?

Comment: Nice. I did not know that this HTML tag exists. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the  **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/v8ykM/3/)** with your given code.

**The Code:**

```
#divPendingQuesTitle
{
    width           : 125px;
    font-size       : 1.2em;
    position        : absolute;
    margin-top      : -25px;
    margin-left     : 5px;
    background      : white;
    padding-left    : 1%;
    padding-right   : 1%;
    color           : #00F;
}
```

I will still suggest you to use legend.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of solution:

```
  <div id="divPendingQues">
    <fieldset id="divPendingQuesContainer">
        <legend>Some Title Text</legend>
        <div style="width : 100%;padding-top: 1%;">
          <div class="divQuesAns">
            <div class="divQues">Some Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
```

The css

```
#divPendingQuesContainer
{
    height      : 50%;
    border      : 2px solid #00F;
    padding     : 1%;
    margin-top  : 1%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#divPendingQues
{
    width       : 100%; 
    height      : 100%;
}
#divPendingQuesTitle
{
    width           : 125px;
    font-size       : 1.2em;
    margin-top      : -25px;
    margin-left     : 5px;
    background      : white;
    padding-left    : 1%;
    padding-right   : 1%;
    color           : #00F;
}
.divQuesAns
{
    border      : 1px solid black;
    padding     : 1%; 
    margin      : 1px;
}
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/v8ykM/4/

Hope this helps